# how to store child process pid (process id)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a simple script to spawn child process and pause and resume  child process. For this, I am storing pid of child process  so that I can pause and resume process

For Example:

```
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGSTOP)  #  for pause

os.kill(pid, signal.SIGCONT) # for resume
```

My code

```
class Multiprocessing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pid = {}

    def worker(self, idd):
        pid = os.getpid()
        self.pid[idd] = pid
        # doing some thing

    def start(self, a):
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
        print os.getpid()
        l = []
        for idd in a:
            p.apply_async(self.worker, (idd,))
            l.append(p)




obj = Multiprocessing()
obj.start()
print obj.pid  # print empty dictionary i.e {}
```

Please help me how to store pid on class object

Comment: Did you put a print in your worker method?

Comment: ya, when i print self.pid it show {"id": pid}  and every worker print its own pid

Comment: use `self.pid = Manager().dict()` after `from multiprocessing import Manager` https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes each child is going to get a copy of the main processes memory so you need to use a manager object

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  thanks for help